# Broadcasting vectors and matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to use a dotted version of a scalar function to calculate values for an entire matrix of inputs. The function is defined as follows:

```
function SpecificCharge(U, r, B)
 ( 2 * U ) / ( r^2 * B^2 )
end
```

and I would like to give it the following inputs:

```
const Us = [ # voltages U
  228.9, 243, 257, 271, 285, 300
]

const Rs = [ # radii r
  9 7 5.8 5 4.3 3.9;
  10.5 8.1 6.7 5.7 4.9 4.5;
  10.1 8.3 7.1 6.5 6 4.8;
  11.1 9.0 7.2 6.5 5.6 5.1;
  10.5 8.3 7.8 6.5 5.7 5.4;
  11.9 8.9 8.0 7.4 6.2 5.5
]

const Bs = [ # flux densities B
  0.0007332339999999999, 0.00089328, 0.0010421599999999999, 0.00119104, 0.00133992, 0.0014873112
]

# Calling the dotted version of the function
specific_charges = SpecificCharge.(Us, Rs, Bs)
```

The result should be a matrix of same dimensions as `Rs`, with each radius replaced by the corresponding specific charge, given by `SpecificCharge`. There is one flux density corresponding to each `U`--`B` pair, and the rows in `Rs` correspond to voltages `U` and columns to flux densities `B`.

The problem is, I'm not sure how broadcasting works in Julia. Does the function `SpecificCharge.` work as is, if I just transpose the vectors `Us` and `Bs` appropriately, or do I need to complicate the function itself to make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does the function `SpecificCharge`. work as is, if I just transpose the vectors `Us` and `Bs` appropriately, or do I need to complicate the function itself to make this work?

Did you try it? It works as written, however, I am guessing you want to transpose either `Us` or `Bs` to get the correct "coupling".

---

When you use broadcast with different array dimensions (vectors and matrices in your example) Julia will "extend" arrays in the singleton dimensions. E.g. a vector will be extended to a matrix with a copy of the vector in each column. Here is an example to illustrate this

```
julia> A = ["A1", "A2"];

julia> B = ["B11" "B12" "B13";
            "B21" "B22" "B23"];

julia> f(args...) = join(args, ", ");

julia> f.(A, B)
2×3 Array{String,2}:
 "A1, B11"  "A1, B12"  "A1, B13"
 "A2, B21"  "A2, B22"  "A2, B23"
```

As you can see, the vector `A` has been extended in the singleton dimension to

```
julia> A2 = [A A A]
2×3 Array{String,2}:
 "A1"  "A1"  "A1"
 "A2"  "A2"  "A2"
```

such that it has the same size as `B`, and then `f` is applied to each pair. To extend a vector in the other dimension you need to permute it;

```
julia> C = ["C1", "C2", "C3"];

julia> f.(B, permutedims(C))
2×3 Array{String,2}:
 "B11, C1"  "B12, C2"  "B13, C3"
 "B21, C1"  "B22, C2"  "B23, C3"
```

and now `C` has been extended in the first dimension (the singleton dimension), essentially

```
julia> C2 = [permutedims(C); permutedims(C); permutedims(C)]
3×3 Array{String,2}:
 "C1"  "C2"  "C3"
 "C1"  "C2"  "C3"
 "C1"  "C2"  "C3"
```